# Accord.NET machine learning on table data to predict next row

Tags: c#, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, id3, accord.net

Ok, I have these huge data sets I want to analyze, and most of the column values relate to one or more values in other columns. Here is a simple example, in reality there are many more columns:

```
    t     c1     c2     c3     c4
    0   21.0    2.0   54.2    0.1
   15   22.2    2.2   51.5    0.2
   30   24.4    2.9   52.3    0.4
   45   19.1    3.2   58.7    0.7
   60   18.6    3.4   61.3    0.6
   75   ??.?    ?.?   ??.?    ?.?
   90   ??.?    ?.?   ??.?    ?.?
```

To simplify, I have logged values with equal time intervals for a long time, and now I want to predict the values for c1, c2, c3 and c4 at t=75 and t=90.

If I make arrays out of these column values, eg:

```
float[] c1Array = { 21.0, 22.2, 24.4, 19.1, 18.6 };
float[] c2Array = { 2.0, 2.2, 2.9, 3.2, 3.4};
float[] c3Array = { 54.2,........61.3}

and so on...

eg.
c1Array[2] would inter-correspond with c2Array[2], c3Array[2] etc...
```

How would I utilize Accord.NET machine learning, and what are my options? I've read a bit upon using DecisionTree and ID3Learning - and it looks like that can solve my problem:

[A simple example with just x and y values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40573388/simple-accord-net-machine-learning-example) (I need an example with x, y, z,....)

But then I came over [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/541428/Sequence-Classifiers-in-Csharp-Part-I-Hidden-Marko), which is Hidden Markov Models in Accord.NET, and it seems like that might be a better fit.

I am a programmer, not a mathematician, and I find most examples tend to operate with single data sets that would have 1 or two "columns", I need to work on multiple.

I could work with something like the x and y values example I linked above, but with using more columns.

But if there are better functions in my case, I would love to see some examples.

Comment: Hi there - do you mean you have a variable number of input variables that you would like to use to predict a particular column? Or just that you have an actually fixed number of input variables, but that you would like to use just a subset of, to predict a particular column?

Comment: Ok, re-reading your question again, I am afraid you might need to disclose a bit more what your variables (and their observation over time) actually mean. There might be different strategies that can be adopted depending on that. Also, please consider posting an example of the data you are trying to learn in the Accord.NET's issue tracker to make things faster to solve.

Comment: I will update and rewrite the question a bit once I get physical access to a good example data set.

I cannot fully disclose what these values are linked to, but I can tell you that each single cell is representing the performance of a product (e.g % increase/decrease since last time it was logged). If one cell has an increase or decrease it is more or less directly related to the combination of all decrease/increase values in the other cells on that row and the previous rows. I will get back with a more refined question and a bounty.